# Force user to input only Y or N in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to programming and my first assessment is to create a program that asks a few questions to the user.

The first question requires the user to answer "**Y**" or "**N**" and I would like to force the user to only do it, by keep asking them the same question until the user types "**Y**" or "**N**", without accepting any other letters or numbers or symbols.

If the answer in "**N**", then the user is asked another question (which is apparently working for me) and so on.

I am trying to use a while loop and now I'm lost:

```
print("Phase vaccine rollout (PVR) v1.0")
print("==========================")

phase1a = input("Are you a quarantine and border worker,\n\
    prioritised frontline healthcare worker, or\n\
    an aged care/disability care staff member or resident (Y/N)?: ")

while phase1a.upper() == "Y" or "N":

    if phase1a.upper() == "Y":
        print()
        print("Vaccines will be made available to you in Phase 1a")
        print()
        exit()

    elif phase1a.upper() == "N":
        print("__________________________")
        phase1b = input("Are you a health care worker, or\n\
            a critical or high risk worker (including defence,\n\
            police, fire, emergency services and meat processing (Y/N)?: ")
        continue

    else:
        break
```

*# --- and from here I will continue with the phase1b...*

Comment: `while phase1a.upper() == "Y" or "N"` is not the right way to check for multiple values.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`a == x or y or z\` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be using while True that will end with a else statement which will ask for the user to repeat their input if it is not Y/N.
Also to note:
You will have to add the result if the user inputs N.

```
print("Phase vaccine rollout (PVR) v1.0")
print("==========================")

phase1a = input("Are you a quarantine and border worker,\n\
prioritised frontline healthcare worker, or\n\
an aged care/disability care staff member or resident (Y/N)?: ")

while  True:

    if phase1a.upper() == "Y":
    
        print("\nVaccines will be made available to you in Phase 1a\n")
   
        exit()

    elif phase1a.upper() == "N":
        print("__________________________")
        phase1b = input("Are you a health care worker, or\n\
        a critical or high risk worker (including defence,\n\
        police, fire, emergency services and meat processing (Y/N)?: ")
        break

   else:
       phase1a = input("\nAre you a quarantine and border worker,\n\
       prioritised frontline healthcare worker, or\n\
       an aged care/disability care staff member or resident (Y/N)?: ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `while True` loop will do the trick....

```
print("Phase vaccine rollout (PVR) v1.0")
print("==========================")

while True:
    phase1a = input("Are you a quarantine and border worker,\n\
       prioritised frontline healthcare worker, or\n\
       an aged care/disability care staff member or resident (Y/N)?: ")
    if phase1a.upper() == "Y":
        print()
        print("Vaccines will be made available to you in Phase 1a")
        print()
        exit()

    elif phase1a.upper() == "N":
        print("__________________________")
        phase1b = input("Are you a health care worker, or\n\
            a critical or high risk worker (including defence,\n\
            police, fire, emergency services and meat processing (Y/N)?: ")
        exit()
    else:
        continue

# --- and from here I will continue with the phase1b...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while phase1a.upper() == "Y" or "N":`, you could write:

```
while phase1a.upper() != "Y" and phase1a.upper() != "N":
  print("Invalid input. Please enter "Y" or "N".)
  phase1a = input("Are you a quarantine and border worker,\n\
  prioritised frontline healthcare worker, or\n\
  an aged care/disability care staff member or resident (Y/N)?: ")
```

You will have to restructure your `if` statement a bit but hopefully this shows you the idea. This will force the user to keep entering input until he/she enters "Y" or "N".

Comment: `while phase1a.upper() != "Y" or phase1a.upper() != "N"` will always be true, no matter what is entered.  You meant to use `and` insead of `or`.